# Permutation of numbers - all possible combinations

Tags: algorithm, delphi, permutation

I am trying to calculate all the possible combinations of numbers given. However, my code doesn't seem to be calculating all the values.

```
function TForm2.GetNextPerm(s: string): string;
var
    i, j, n : integer;
    t : Char;
    tempString : string;
begin
    result := s;

    //step 1
    i := length(s);
    for n := length(s) - 1 downto 1 do begin
      i := n;
      if (s[i] < s[i + 1]) then break;
    end;
    if (s[i] >= s[i + 1]) then exit;   //already at last permutation

    //step 2
    j := length(s);
    for n := length(s) downto 2 do begin
      j := n;
      if (s[j] > s[i]) then break;
    end;

    //step 3
    t := s[i];
    s[i] := s[j];
    s[j] := t;

    //step 4
    tempString := '';
    for n := length(s) downto i + 1 do
      tempString := tempString + copy(s, n, 1);
    if (tempString <> '') then s := copy(s, 1, i) + tempString;

    result := s;
end;


procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, t: string;
  i: integer;
  x: integer;
  hash: string;
  o: string;
begin

  s := '0123';
  o := '0123';

  for x := 4 to 9 do
  begin
    t := GetNextPerm(s);
    while (s <> t) do
    begin

      hash := GenerateHashFromPasscode(s);
      if s = '76543210' then
        //Do stuff - Never gets here

     // if AnsiCompareText(hash, Edit1.Text) =0 then
       // ShowMessage('Match! ' + s);
      s := t;
      t := GetNextPerm(s);
    end;

    s := o + IntToStr(x);
    o := o + IntTOStr(x);
  end;
end;
```

I've spent hours trying to figure out why this isn't working as it should. Maybe a fresh set of eyes will help. The idea is that it will start producing all the possible combinations with the numbers `0123`. After that, it will find all the possible combinations with the numbers `01234` etc, all the way up to `012345678`.

Comment: So you mean for `0123` it will generate `0123`, `0132`, `0213`, `0231`, etc.? In other words, permutations of the set of symbols `0123`, never something like `0000`, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. There should be no repetition.

Comment: I don't have time to dig deeply into this now, but I recommend running this in the debugger, or at least printing out intermediate values. Watching it run line by line should reveal where it goes wrong. I bet there are standard algorithms for this, too, which is why I added the algorithm and permutation tags to it.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Delphi

Comment: @Jake Did you do a websearch?